# Change the bg image for different Joomla menu pages with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla

I try to alter the background image for every Joomla menu page I got (example.com/joomla/index.php/page1, .../index.php/page2, and so on.

So I created this jQuery function that changes the bg image on click of a menu button.

```
$('#page1').on('click', function() {
$('#background').css('background-image','url(http://example.com/joomla/templates/template/images/page1.jpg)'); })
```

The background actually changes for a second, but as soon page1 finished loading, the standard (page0) bg is shown.

Comment: What do you mean as soon as it finished loading? Are you saying that you're clicking the menu item to change the BG but your page has such a long load time that it's not fully rendered all DOM elements (including, and presumably, a script that changes the bg) and something executes towards the end of the page that causes the bg to change back? Or are you saying it changes when you go to a new page again.

Comment: Whyare you choosing to use jQuery for this rather than CSS?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy The loading time is not that long. The BG changes on click, and at the end of the 0.5 seconds it takes to load the other page, the BG changes back.

Comment: @Lodder Well, it is a joomla template, so I can't make a CSS for every page. I never heard about a possibility to alter the BG url for different  pages with the same css

Comment: @titaniumduck You can do this by leveraging the attributes selector. [a\[href="http://example.com/joomla/index.php/page1"\]{ background:blue;}](http://jsfiddle.net/9d0ugoof/)